# Android AsyncTask Error implement abstract

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to understand how AsyncTask works. I have the following code, but I get the following error: Class 'AsyncTask' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'doInBackground(Params...)'

```
private class WeatherDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackgrond() throws Exception{
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            String data = null;
            try{
                URL url = new URL("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=90210,us&units=imperial");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    data = null;
                }
                return data = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                data = null;
                return data;
            } finally{
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String jsonParse){
            if(jsonParse == null){
                TextView progress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.container);
                progress.setText("Unable to get weather");
            }
            else {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(jsonParse);
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(jsonRootObject.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp"));
                    TextView displayTemp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.container);
                    displayTemp.setText(temp);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm just trying to get the temperature and update the textview. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change `doInBackgrond() throws Exception` to `doInBackground(Void... params)`

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and I'm still getting the same error. Do I need to override the method also?

Comment: maybe you also need to remove `throws Exception` from `doInBackgrond()`.. and you have typo: `doInBackgrond()` instead of `doInBackground()`

Comment: @Override notation is optional

Comment: doInBackground cannot throw an exception from the method itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

```
private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) throws Exception{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the method in the AsyncTask source

```
 /**
 * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread. The
 * specified parameters are the parameters passed to {@link #execute}
 * by the caller of this task.
 *
 * This method can call {@link #publishProgress} to publish updates
 * on the UI thread.
 *
 * @param params The parameters of the task.
 *
 * @return A result, defined by the subclass of this task.
 *
 * @see #onPreExecute()
 * @see #onPostExecute
 * @see #publishProgress
 */
protected abstract Result doInBackground(Params... params);
```

Notice it doesn't throw an exception, so by having "throws Exception" in there means you are not overriding the super class method and clashing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Override to doInBackground method, when you extends AsyncTask at least you must override doInBackground method. 
Remove throws.
doInBackground is said not your "doInBackgrond" typo

Comment: When I add @Override I get the error: "Method does not override from its superclass"